# How can I display a single and two quotes in a number using a variable not literal in C++? Let's say 6'2" feet

Tags: c++

I'm new using C++, my instructor wants me to print this sentence:

> A 6'2" person is 74.4 inches tall

The thing is I don't know how to put the quotes, and he doesn't let me use 6 and 2, he wants me to use the variable that I previously declared for 6'2". I don't have idea how to put quotes in a variable. Also that same variable that I previously declared as height_feet, it's been using to compute a calculation, so I can't declare it as string(can I?).

```
double height_feet = 6.2;
double height inches = height_feet * 12);
cout << "A " << height_feet << " person is " << height_inches<< " inches tall " << endl;
```

Comment: look up backslash to escape the normal processing of a char. Put it in the char string litterals

Comment: `height_feet = "6\'2\""`

Comment: Just about any descent book ([here's a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) of good ones) or tutorial should have taught you how to *escape* special characters in a string.

Comment: @v78 single quotes don't need to be escaped inside double quotes and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

You can escape them in a string like this:

```
  string height = "6\'2\"";
  cout << "A " << height << " person is " << 1.88<< " meters tall " << endl;
```

Just put a slash before " or ' which you want to include as part of the string rather than part of the code.

@iammilind pointed out that you don't technically require escaping for the single quote if it is between double quotes, so whether or not you escape that is optional.

Comment: No escape is required for single quote `'`, when it appears between double quotes, i.e. `"hello 'x'."` is fine. It will be required when appearing between single quotes, such as `'\''`.

Comment: I made that change.